# Reverse proxy reduces download speed

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, remote-server, ssh-tunnel, bandwidth

There are two servers: `alpha` and `beta`. Alpha is publicly accessible with the address `alpha.com`, and `beta` is in the local network of `alpha` at address `192.168.0.1`, not publicly accessible. And let's call my computer `home`, which is not in the local network of `alpha`.

I am launching [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org) servers on:

- `alpha` at address `alpha.com:2001`
- `beta` at address `192.168.0.1:2002`
- `beta` at address `localhost:2003`

additionally, I am setting up a *nginx reverse proxy* on `alpha` that links `192.168.0.1:2002` and `alpha.com:2002`. Also, I use ssh tunnel between `localhost:2003` and `alpha.com:2003` using the command `ssh -fNT -L 0.0.0.0:2003:localhost:2003 beta`

There are copies of a large fie (~20GB) on both servers; `A.dat` on `alpha` and `B.dat` on `beta`.

Below is the illustration of the setup:

```
         ______nginx________
        /                   \
    beta                    alpha ----------- home
     |  \______ssh__________/ |
     |                        |  
  "B.dat"                   "A.dat"
     |                        |
     |                   alpha.com:2001
192.168.0.1:2002  ---->  alpha.com:2002
localhost:2003    ---->  alpha.com:2003
```

I am putting a large file (~20GB) on both servers.
I am loging in to each of the computers (by remote desktop) and downloading the file.

On the computer `alpha`:

- downloading `A.dat` from `alpha.com:2001`: 130 MByte/sec
- downloading `B.dat` from `alpha.com:2002`: 80 MByte/sec
- downloading `B.dat` from `alpha.com:2003`: 90 MByte/sec
- downloading `B.dat` from `192.168.0.1:2002` to `alpha`: 90 MByte/sec

On the computer `beta`:

- downloading `A.dat` from `alpha.com:2001`: 80 MByte/sec
- downloading `B.dat` from `alpha.com:2002`: 50 MByte/sec
- downloading `B.dat` from `alpha.com:2003`: 50 MByte/sec
- downloading `B.dat` from `192.168.0.1:2002`: 60 MByte/sec
- downloading `B.dat` from `localhost:2003`: 60 MByte/sec

On the computer `home`:

- downloading `A.dat` from `alpha.com:2001`: 30 MByte/sec
- **downloading `B.dat` from `alpha.com:2002`: 5 MByte/sec**
- **downloading `B.dat` from `alpha.com:2003`: 6 MByte/sec**

We can see that there is high bandwidth between `alpha` and `beta`, and sufficiently high bandwidth between `alpha` and `home` (~30 MB/sec).

I cannot understand why the bandwidth is so low between `home` and `beta` through `alpha`. How can I fix this? Please let me know if more information is needed about the setup. Thanks in advance.